# how to upload multiple inputs using formdata

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which has two different type of inputs. one is type='file' and another is type='text'.
Now I'm trying to send these inputs to my database by using formdata() in jquery but what ever I do I can't send both inputs.

```
<form class='form-group' id='first_banner_form' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <label class='btn btn-warning btn-block textbutton'>
    upload your image<input type='file' class='hidden' 
    name='banner_number_one' id='banner_number_one'/>
    </label>

    <br>

    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='banner_number_one_addr' id='banner_number_one_addr'
    placeholder='write your name' style='text-align:center'/>
    <hr>

    </form>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <button class='btn btn-success btn-block textbutton' id='upload_a_banner'>Upload</button>
```

and this is my jquery code

```
    $(document).on('click','#upload_a_banner',function(){

    var banner_form = new FormData($('#first_banner_form')[0]);



    $.ajax({
        url:'phpScript/upload_new_banners.php',
        method:'POST',
        data:banner_form,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data)
        {
            if(data=='done')
            {
                alert('uploaded');
            }elseif(data=='file is not set')
      { alert('database couldn\'t recieve all data'); 
 }
else{
            alert(data);
            }

        },error:function()
        {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

});
```

and this is php code

```
if(isset($_FILES['banner_number_one']) && isset($_FILES['banner_number_one_addr']))
{
    # the image
    $fr_banner_name = $_FILES['banner_number_one']['name'];
    $fr_banner_temp = $_FILES['banner_number_one']['tmp_name'];

    #the link
    $fr_link = $_FILES['banner_number_one_addr']['name'];



}else{
    echo 'file is not set';
        exit;
}
```

when I just write

```
if(isset($_FILES['banner_number_one']))
```

everything works but when I write

```
 if(isset($_FILES['banner_number_one']) &&   isset($_FILES['banner_number_one_addr']))
```

I recieve 'file is not set' message. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `banner_number_one_addr` is in `$_POST` array:

`$_POST['banner_number_one_addr']`

Answer (score 1):

`banner_number_one_addr` is part of $_POST so use `isset($_POST['banner_number_one_addr'])` instead of `isset($_FILE['banner_number_one_addr'])`

```
if(isset($_FILES['banner_number_one']) &&   isset($_POST['banner_number_one_addr'])){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because banner_number_one_addr is in $_POST array:

$_POST['banner_number_one_addr']